# _fstream->is_open() fialed Error while running gem5 python script

Tags: python, gem5

I have built the gem5 successfully but when I am trying to run `se.py` file using following command:

```
./build/X86/gem5.opt ./configs/example/se.py -c ./tests/test-progs/hello/bin/alpha/linux/hello
```

it gives me error as `assertion '_fstream->is_open() failed`'.
I am attaching screenshot of command I used and error I got. I would be really grateful if someone can help me to resolve this issue. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flpua.png) for reference.

Comment: Please include all text in the question by copy pasting from the terminal rather than as a screenshot. You seem to be trying to run an alpha executable with an X86 build, try the bin/x86 one.